# can't acces data after mounted iso file on external hard drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, data-recovery, iso

I tried to install a software on my Ubunutu 18.04 computer, but I did it by using an **.iso** file and installed everything on my external hard drive.

After did this, I can't access my data from the external hard drive, I can only enter to the mounted folder corresponding to the softaware...
When I chose the external hard drive as space to install the software, I thought it was just to choose free large space, to create an installation folder, not to *mount* it and no have access to my past data...

I knew there are some solutions to recover data such as **Testdisk**, but I feel completely lost, since I don't know what I did wrong and such Testdisk didn't solve it. I just want to have access again to my personnal data within the external hard drive.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: What software did you install? Why did you install it in an external drive (and not in the standard locations)?

Comment: The software was **COMSOL**. I installed it on an external drive since I thought it will take only free space, and ths was more interesting for me to do it on external drive instead of computer.

Comment: Please try again, this time follow the instructions from the COMSOL web page (e.g. [this link](https://www.comsol.com/support/knowledgebase/1086)], where they suggest "To install your COMSOL software products in a system directory such as `/usr/local`, you might need to run the installation program as the root user."